# Mongo Aggregation slow when adding group

Tags: mongodb

Here is a fast query that returns 5 documents:

```
db.getCollection('rels').aggregate([{$match: {
  "aui2": "A7592922",
  "suppressible": false,
  "stype1":"SCUI",
  "stype2":"SCUI"
}}, 
])
```

However, when I add group, it becomes extremely slow, as in over 3 minutes

```
db.getCollection('rels').aggregate([{$match: {
  "aui2": "A7592922",
  "suppressible": false,
  "stype1":"SCUI",
  "stype2":"SCUI"
}},
{
    $group:
        {
            _id: { relationLabel: '$additionalRelationLabel'},
            relationCount: { $sum: 1 },
        }
}
])
```

I can't understand why adding $group after a phase that matched 5 documents would be so slow. All fields queried are being indexed, including additionalRelationLabel

Comment: Hi, please use the explain method and add the output to the question. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation